# Private files not showing up on github

Tags: github, meteor

I am using Github for version control and Heroku for app hosting. My app is built using Meteor JS. My app folder has a folder called `private` and it contains .json files. I pushed my master copy onto github, but the files in my private folder are not there. My steps:

```
git add .
git commit -m 'push to master'
git push origin master
```

I checked my private folder after following these steps but the files are not there. I have confirmed that the files are in my local private folder. Can someone help?

Thanks!

Comment: where were you when you executed the `git add .` command?

Comment: i was in the app root directory

Comment: do you have a `.gitignore` file? What do you get when you run `git status`?